# Html.DisplayFor shows tags as plain text

Tags: c#, html, razor, displayfor

```
<div id="contact-description">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot of output text]

This is the output this code gives, while the output should only be "Test". How to hide the Span tag?

Comment: Can you please expand on what you mean by shows the `tags`?

Comment: Could you more elaborate your question please?

Comment: Edited the question with a screenshot

Comment: Is the `span style` being printed out on the page or is it in the DOM?

Comment: @Liam or you can just use `@Model.Description`

Comment: This will still delimit the HTML. You need to use Raw if the string contains restricted tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming your Description property value contains HTML tags (the `<span>`):

You want `@Html.Raw(Model.Description)`. `@Html.DisplayFor` will automatically delimit HTML to prevent HTML injection. If your expecting HMTL output use `Raw()`

Comment: Please note when using `@Html.Raw()` the output will not be HTML encoded. This does mean that your site could be vulnerable to XSS injection.